# AC golfing - shortest form of Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Sometimes — especially when dealing with classes that may not be models of some basic axioms, such as the separation axioms — one needs to cloister himself in the original language $L$ of set theory, that is the language generated by $\in$. If you have to relativise a form of AC in one of these classes, it is convenient to have it as short as possible.

We can define the length of a formula as the number of nodes in its tree structure. Abbreviations such as $∀x∈y\ F$ need to be expanded, while $\leftrightarrow$ can be used.

So far, the shortest form of AC (which ZF proves to be equivalent to AC) I've come across is a translation of 
$$\forall u \bigl(\varnothing ∉ u \land ∀x,y∈ u (x≠y \rightarrow x \cap y = \varnothing) \rightarrow ∃w∀x∈u∃y(x\cap w = \{y\})\bigr)  $$
into $L$. I replaced

1. $\varnothing ∈ u$ with $∀x(x∈u \rightarrow ∃y(y∈x))$ (11 nodes)
2. $x≠y \rightarrow x \cap y = \varnothing$ with $∃z(z∈x\land z∈y) \rightarrow x=y$ (13 nodes)
3. $x\cap w = \{y\}$ with $∀z(z∈x \land z∈w \leftrightarrow z=y)$ (13 nodes)

Summing all up, you get a total of <s>71</s> 64 nodes. My question is, is there any known equivalent (in ZF) form of AC which is shorter than the one above (once translated into $L$)?

[Boring] bonus questions: what are the formulas in $L$ with the lowest number of nodes, which ZF proves to be equivalent to the Axiom of Choice? What if we drop some axioms from ZF?

Comment: What you wrote is *probably* the shortest form. Because most other forms would require you to first talk about functions or relations in one way or another. I don't think anyone bothered to sit down and search for such "shortest form", and I don't expect anyone would waste time by verifying that there is no shorter form than the one suggested in your question.

Comment: Your suggested axiom is false for $u=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: To throw something into the ring, I think something like $\forall u(\emptyset\notin u\to \exists w\forall x\in u\exists y\in x\forall z\in x(z=y\leftrightarrow\exists p\in u(z\in p\land x\in p)))$ might allow for a short translation into $L$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, also note that $\varnothing$ is not even in the language of set theory. So you need to replace it by $\exists z(z\in\ldots)$, and $\neq$ is actually $\lnot(x=y)$, and so on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There are many issues with the formula as written but I thought that this is why OP wrote "can be rewritten in $L$ using 71 nodes."  Besides what you've already mentioned: Bounded quantification is an abbreviation, $\cap$, $x = \{y\}$ need to be replaced by their respective defining formulae. But, yeah, I agree. I don't see the point of this exercise.

Comment: You are right! I acknowledge that what I find interesting usually turns out to be really boring to the others. I'm sorry about it. I'll try to patch up the question asap.

Comment: Beside that, I just want to point out that my example is not written in $L$—you need to translate it before counting. For instance, $\varnothing ∉u$ can be replaced by $∀x(x∈u \rightarrow ∃y(y∈x)$, which counts for $11$ nodes.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I don't understand your comments and there's a $w$ hanging there for reasons unknown to me.